# CSS select all the matching nodes connecting directly from body

Tags: css

Here is my HTML that is some sort of

```
- body
  - #yes1.parent
   - #no1.other
     - #no2.parent
       - #no3.parent
   - #yes2.parent
     - #yes3.parent
       - #yes4.parent
```

And here is the equivalent in HTML

```
<body>
  <div id="yes1" class="parent">
    <div id="no1" class="other">
      <div id="no2" class="parent">
        <div id="no3" class="parent"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="yes2" class="parent">
      <div id="yes3" class="parent">
        <div id="yes4" class="parent"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

The type of selector I would like to be if selectors were full regular expressions:

```
body (> .parent > .parent)*
```

So that I would match all the yes1-4 and not match the nos. For example,

```
.parent > .parent
```

would not work since it will also match no2 and no3 which don't directly connect to body since the parent of #no2 is not a .parent.

Is there a valid CSS selector that would do that ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Build a navigation menu or something else?

Comment: Assuming the DIVs *actually* have an ID that start with 'yes', you could just use `div[id^="yes"]`. Or are you unable to set the IDs?

Comment: I want to understand if there exist a selector that could select that

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach but requires 2 classes though:

1. Impact just `.parent` to cover all of them.
2. Impact `.parent [id^=no]` to isolate divs starting with id="no" inside any `.parent`.

```css
.parent {
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  padding: 10px;
  background: green;
}
.parent [id^=no] {
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  padding: 10px;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="yes1" class="parent">
    <div id="no1" class="other">
      <div id="no2" class="parent">
        <div id="no3" class="parent"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="yes2" class="parent">
      <div id="yes3" class="parent">
        <div id="yes4" class="parent"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://fiddle.jshell.net/m35r2995/2/

Check the fiddle:

I would go for the selector ".parent .parent" and the value "inherit"

```
.parent{
  background-color: #00ff00;
}
.parent .parent{
  background-color: inherit;
}
.other{
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```